# What does set str1=#%str1% mean in batch script, why it accidently performing file overwrite?

Tags: windows, batch-file

What does set str1=#%str1% mean in batch script, why it accidently performing file overwrite if line contains any < or >?

I've written batch script to read log file line by line and output, if any error extract LineNo and ErrorNo and output in Visual Studio Output window compliant format so that error code jump works.

But while code works perfectly in formatting output, if log line contains > < it is performing file operation instead of just evaluation and display. Following 2 result in creation of file named "(parameter" and overwriting "abc.xyz"

example 1: creates file named "(parameter"

`mytool: line 63, &rem. 541 , can not omit value. ===> (parameter no 1)`

example 2: overwriting "abc.xyz"

`mytool: line 0, &rem. 5 , file is abnormal. ===> C:\Projects\abc_DemoSampleExample\abc\my\abc.xyz`

`rem set str1=#%str1%`
stops file overwrite but breaks code as output is not finding LineNo and ErrorNo.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (Build.log) do call :Process "%%A" %1
goto :eof

:Process
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  call :GetLineError %1 LineNo ErrorNo
  echo."%2(!LineNo!):error(!ErrorNo!):" %1
goto :eof


:GetLineError
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set string="%~1"
rem set "string=%string:<=#%"
rem set "string=%string:>=#%"
set "find_index_of=error code:"

call :indexof %string% "%find_index_of%" index

:indexof [%1 - string ; %2 - find index of ; %3 - if defined will store the result in variable with same name]

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion     
set "str=%~1"
set "str1=!str:%~2=&rem.!"

REM This line appears to be causing the problem
set str2=#%str1%

call :strLen str2 strlen
rem echo.String is %strlen% characters long
(endlocal & set "%3=%strlen%")
exit /b

:strLen
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:strLen_Loop

   if not "!%1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1 & goto :strLen_Loop
(endlocal & set %2=%len%)
goto :eof
```

UPDATE 1:
above unnecessary code removed to compact code.

above bat is invoked as `MyBat.bat build.log` after CD in that folder.

build.log contents

```
Preprocessing abc.xyz ...
mytool: line 66, error code:  541 ,    can not omit value. ===> (parameter no 1)
abc.xyz - 1 error(s)
Program has exited with code -1
mytool: line 0, error code:    5 ,    file is abnormal. ===> C:\Projects\abc_DemoSampleExample\abc\my\abc.xyz
```

here abc.xyz file in current folder is getting overwritten on processing 2nd error msg and `rem set str2=#%str1%` stops file overwrite but gives wrong lineNo and errorNo also(as now instead of substring, whole modified line is read so length comes 74 instead of 17 for error1, and 122 instead of 16 in error2).

can someone kindly suggest mistake and correction?

UPDATE 2:
following code snippet

```
set "str=%~1"
set "str1=!str:%~2=&rem.!"
set str2=#%str1%

echo %str1%
echo !str1!
echo !%str1%!
echo %str2%
echo !str2!
echo !%str2%!

call :strLen str1 strlen
(endlocal & set "%3=%strlen%")
exit /b

:strLen
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:strLen_Loop
   if not "!%1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1 & goto :strLen_Loop
```

give following output for error 1 and error 2:

```
mytool: line 63,
mytool: line 63, &rem.  541 ,    can not omit value. ===> (parameter no 1)
 line 63,
#mytool: line 63,
#mytool: line 63,
 line 63,
74
mytool: line 0,
mytool: line 0, &rem.    5 ,    file is abnormal. ===> C:\Projects\abc_DemoSampleExample\abc\my\abc.xyz
 line 0,
#mytool: line 0,
#mytool: line 0,
 line 0,
122
```

All I want is get substring before &rem. so that index before error code can be found (index 17 for error1 and 16 for error2). and it should not result in file abc.xyz overwrite operation.

Comment: You haven't told us what `%1` and `%2` are. You haven't provided any sample data from `build.log` (obfuscated as necessary). There appears to be no code to output to a file, so how it's overwriting the input file is a mystery. Batch has no concept of `sections` or `procedures`, it just executes code line-by-line until it reaches a `goto`. Consequently, having `call`ed `:indexof` it will contineu to execute `:indexof` a second time.  More data required, please.

Comment: The statement `set str1=#%str1%` normally inserts `#` at the beginning of `str1` but the previous line may replace some string with `&rem `, so the code executed in that case would be `set str2=#[the part of %1 before %2]&rem [the part of %1 after %2]` . Without example data - difficult to describe.

Comment: @Magoo thanks for comment, your explanation is right. I have echod most lines, but in any case it would result in blank abc.xyz File overwrite operation, is out of my mind. I've updated my question with bat file invocation command as well as build.log file contents. Code is shortened by removing goto, endlocal and lineNo, ErrorNo formatting, set return parameters etc. commands.

Comment: Two short notes: It would really help if you extracted a [mcve] from your code, including all input data and the expected output, so people here can reproduce it without guessing. That said, I personally invested lots of time in batch scripting, but consider that obsolete knowledge. I'd use Powershell if I was writing code specifically for Windows or Python if it was of a more general use, but avoid cmd.exe. Don't waste your time on learning obsolete programming languages!

Comment: @Magoo can someone explain, for Error 2 How
echo !str1! prints
mytool: line 0, &rem.    5 ,    file is abnormal. ===> C:\Projects\abc_DemoSampleExample\abc\my\abc.xyz

while echo !str2! prints
#mytool: line 0,

Comment: if log line contains > < it is performing file operation instead of just evaluation and display. following 2 result in creation of file named "(parameter" and overwriting "abc.xyz"
example 1:
mytool: line 63, &rem.  541 ,    can not omit value. ===> (parameter no 1)
example 2:
mytool: line 0, &rem.    5 ,    file is abnormal. ===> C:\Projects\abc_DemoSampleExample\abc\my\abc.xyz

Answer (score 0):

Your question is, how to get the information from a line of the format:

```
mytool: line 66, error code:  541 ,    can not omit value. ===> (parameter no 1)
```

You tried `set "str1=!str:%~2=&rem.!"` but that's only a hack, and is not bullet proof nor reliable.

But in your case, you could simply split the line with:

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%L in (Build.log) do (
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,* delims=:," in %%1 in ("%%L") do (
       echo File: "%%1" in "%%2" errCode "%%4" msg "%%5"     
    )
)
```