# which script dont need any software setup or config

Tags: client-side, windows-scripting

Apart from Batch script, which script I can use that don't need installation or configuration at client system and can be invoked from windows visual studio?

powershell python etc. needs installation.

I'm working on Visual studio build output formatting task, so using batch scrip, but facing lots of unfixable issues as reported below. if log line contains > < it is performing file operation instead of just evaluation and display.
[What does set str1=#%str1% mean in batch script, why it accidently performing file overwrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649620/what-does-set-str1-str1-mean-in-batch-script-why-it-accidently-performing-fi)

Comment: Some version of Powershell is installed with windows so you don't need to install it. But yes, depending on what you do, you might need to install modules. I always fall back to VBScript which is pretty much out of date but a lot friendlier than batch script

Comment: You should be able to do a bunch of generic file manipulation with whatever old Powershell version is installed on windows.